# How to enable multiple column sorting on a (group)table programmatically?

Tags: vaadin, cuba-platform

How can I sort a grouptable multiple? I want to enable the sorting for a user. In addition I want to set the sorting programmatic.

For example: A Customer has many orders. In the table I want to see all orders sorted by order number for a user. The table should be sorted by `customer.name` and `customer.order*.orderNumber`.

Comment: What us a group table? What do you have some far, can you show some code?

Answer (score 2):

`GroupTable` as well as `Table` does not support sorting by multiple columns at runtime.

But you can set a predefined order in the datasource query and disable sorting in table (set `sortable` attribute to false). The predefined order can be set depending on the current user: just modify the query `order by` clause in the `init()` method of the screen.

Comment: Could I unwrap the component and use vaadin component directly?